# Why does IntelliJ install Scala SDK in /home/<user/.ivy2/cache/?

Tags: 14.04, intellij

I have installed IntelliJ and the Scala SDK using the installation wizard provided by IntelliJ. I selected the latest version 2.11.8 but were not able to run it in the terminal.

After that I ran

```
sudo apt-get install scala
```

and now which is apparently version 2.9.2

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

My question is how I can manage to have only *one* version of scala which is used by IntelliJ *and* all other users on my system.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ doesn't ever, and won't ever, have system level write access to make that.  For the most part, it only touches files in your home directory, or in other system directories you tell it to open files from.

Install `scala` through the package manager, and then configure IntelliJ to use that instead.  Since IntelliJ doesn't have system wide privileges you don't have the ability to have it install and manage `scala` systemwide; this unfortunately leaves you with 2.9.2.

Your only other option for updating/upgrading `scala` would be to find a PPA that has the latest version, but that may introduce other breakages.\

Comment: How would I then introduce `scala` to IntelliJ if I install it using the package manager? It does not seem to be able to find the necessary paths on its own.

Comment: @displayname I'm not fluent in IntelliJ's configuration options.  IntelliJ should have a configuration option for Scala somewhere in its settings where you can change what it uses.  By default, I think IntelliJ and the other products in the company's software that creates that product assume it's not available, and download a copy for its local use; you'll have to go hunting in the IntelliJ settings.